# What is the meaning "what is really about" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

> The big issue in philosophy of physics has been the problem of
>   understanding and interpreting **what** quantum mechanics
>   **is really about**.
>
> -Barry Loewer

What is the meaning of the bold part? I didn't find a proper meaning for this phrase that makes sense with this context. Does it mean "the problem of
understanding and interpreting the essence/nature of quantum mechanics"? or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"What quantum mechanics is really about"* just means *"what quantum mechanics actually is"*, i.e. the definition, what it means etc.

So then we have:

> The big issue in philosophy of physics has been the problem of understanding and interpreting what quantum mechanics actually is.